# Am I allowed to submit a paper that is currently in the works of being published to my school's graduate research symposium?

Tags: publications

I want to present my research at my school's yearly graduate research symposium. I got accepted and will be submitting a paper and a pre-recorded presentation. I am excited and happy to be acknowledged by my school for the research I have done. For context, the same work got accepted into a great conference as well. I was wondering if it was bad practice to submit the paper with minor edits to my school's graduate research symposium?

Comment: Will the symposium result in your paper being published in procedings?

Comment: It will be published in our school's ecommons digital library. I do believe it is accessible to the public.